# Can't find my memory leak in this simple code

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, nullptr

I was 100% positive that I covered all ground in terms of deleting memory from the heap before it was lost, but valgrind seems to disagree. Any help with finding the leak in the following code would be greatly appreciated! I can't seem to figure out what's causing it

```
                    Card * S = new Card[subsetSize];
                    Card * M = nullptr;
                    int subsetPrice = 0, subsetProfit = 0;
                    for(int i = 0; i < subsetSize; i++){
                            S[i] = problemCards[cardIndexesToAdd[i]];
                            subsetPrice += S[i].getPrice();
                            subsetProfit += S[i].getProfit();
                    }

                    // Evaluate the subset's cost and profit
                    if(subsetPrice <= maxToSpend){
                            if(subsetProfit > maxProfit){
                                    maxProfit = subsetProfit;
                                    if(M != nullptr)
                                            delete[] M;
                                    M = S;
                                    S = nullptr;
                                    mSize = subsetSize;
                            }
                    }
                    else{
                            if(S != nullptr){
                                    delete[] S;
                                    S = nullptr;
                            }
                    }
                    // output code for M
                    if(M != nullptr)
                        delete[] M;
```

Comment: So you were 100% positive ... and wrong? o.O

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah, it happens. Thanks for the incredibly unnecessary downvote.

Comment: Those checks for `nullptr` are pointless and can be removed.

Comment: @Mr.Smith: Actually it is, if it can tempt the OP to adjust this behaviour. Then he or she will make less mistakes due to false assumptions, in the future. See the big picture.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit adding checks for nullptr is just habit

Comment: This is not a program, so the code cannot be reasoned about. We have no idea at all what these variables are, what they do, and how they can change. The question is unanswerable. Please present the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you constructed while debugging the problem.

Comment: @JayB: Okay, well, I'm saying that it's a _bad_ habit!

Comment: Have a necessary downvote.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit And I'm disagreeing.  You don't need any other info. The meanings of the variables are irrelevant to the question. The code here creates memory in the heap based on evaluations, outputs the a resulting dynamic array, then attempts to delete it.  I'm missing a detail in covering my tracks (making sure I don't leave unaccounted for memory in the heap), and I'm asking if anyone can help me find this detail. The use of these pointers goes no further than the code presented.

Comment: "The use of these pointers goes no further than the code presented."_ We don't know that from the question, is precisely my point. Next time take the time to present an actual MCVE please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at what you are doing step by step:

1. Allocate memory for S. Set M to point to null.

   ```
   Card * S = new Card[subsetSize];
   Card * M = nullptr;
   ```
2. If condition A (subsetPrice <= maxToSpend) is met, and condition B (subsetProfit > maxProfit) is met, swap M to point the memory allocated for S, and set S to point to null.

   ```
   if (subsetPrice <= maxToSpend){
       if (subsetProfit > maxProfit){
           maxProfit = subsetProfit;
           if (M != nullptr)
               delete[] M;
           M = S;
           S = nullptr;
           mSize = subsetSize;
       }
   }
   ```
3. If condition A was not met, deallocate the memory S is pointing to.

   ```
   else{
       if(S != nullptr){
           delete[] S;
           S = nullptr;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Deallocate the memory M is pointing to.

   ```
   if(M != nullptr)
       delete[] M;
   ```

So if condition A is met, but condition B is not, then S is neither deallocated or transferred over to M! Memory leak.

Answer (score 4):

You leak `S` when `(subsetPrice <= maxToSpend) == true` but `(subsetProfit > maxProfit) == false`.

Comment: Isn't setting M to the address pointed to by S, then setting S to nullptr a valid operation? The memory is still accounted for.

Comment: If `(subsetProfit > maxProfit) == false`, this block won't be executed

Comment: Wow! I can't believe I missed that

Answer (score 1):

Rather than playing detective and tracking down this particular memory leak, I'd advise learning to write your code so you don't cause such problems to start with. The most obvious first point would be to **use `std::vector`** instead of trying to handle all the memory management on your own. There is probably no other single step that can eliminate as many problem as quickly as getting used to doing this.

When you use it, almost all problems of this entire *class* simply cease to exist, because you have an object that owns the memory, and when that object goes out of scope, it releases the memory it owns--entirely automatically. It also works even when/if exceptions are thrown, which your code doesn't even *attempt* to deal with.

```
std::vector<Card> subset(subsetSize);

for (int i=0; i<subsetSize; i++) {
    subset.push_back(problemCards[cardIndexesToAdd[i]]);
    subsetPrice += subset.back().getPrice();
    subsetProfit += subset.back().getProfit();
}

if (subsetProfit > maxProfit && subsetPrice < maxPrice) { 
    maxSubset = std::move(subset);
    maxProfit = subsetProfit;
}

// code to print out maxSubset goes here
```

If you wanted to go even further, you could use (for example) a Boost indirect_iterator in place of your `cardIndexesToAdd`. This would let you apply standard algorithms directly to the subset you care about. With this, you could pretty easily avoid making a copy of the current subset at all--you'd just use the indirect_iterator to iterate over the original collection in-place instead.

You could also define an `operator+` for `Card` that would sum the Price and Profit fields:

```
Card operator+(Card const &left, Card const &right) { 
    return Card(left.price+right.price, left.profit+right.profit);
}
```

With this, and the aforementioned indirect_iterator, adding up the profit for a subset could be something like:

```
Card subset_stats = std::accumulate(subset.begin(), subset.end(), Card());
```

Likewise, we could define a comparison operator for `Card` that produces results based on profit and/or cost:

```
// Assuming we care primarily about maximizing profit, secondarily about
// price, so if one subset produces more profit, it's better. If they produce
// the same profit, the lower cost wins.
bool operator<(Card const &a, Card const &b) { 
    if (a.profit == b.profit)
       return a.price < b.price;
    return b.profit < a.profit;
}
```

With that, we can compare `Card`s directly, like: `if (a < b) ..` and get meaningful results.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this would be a comment but I'm new here and can't do that yet.

No check for nullptr is needed with *new* for out of memory. Thx@jerry-coffin

All of your delete [] are inside if () or nested if () statements. If this leaks, you missed adding an else with a delete [] and you have missing else statements.

This appears to be a snippet but as it is, I see no reason for M or its assignment of S. You should probably consider having a single delete at the end.

Comment: `new` does not return a null pointer in case of being out of memory--it throws an exception (unless you use the `new(nothrow)` form).

Comment: @Jerry Coffin, yes, you are correct. My error. Most of my code goes into applications where the default memory allocation behavior has been overridden with custom libraries (i.e game consoles) where an exception cannot be tolerated.